# List of extra abbreviations for NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to use Python + NLTK to do some heavy-duty sentence tokenization on a gigantic set of articles. Unfortunately, it treats "et al." as the end of a sentence rather than as an abbreviation. I suspect that it'll do the same for other abbreviations, like "e.g." or "i.e."

I know that I can add something like this:

```
sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
extra_abbreviations = ['et al']
sentence_tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(extra_abbreviations)
```

But I don't want to have to manually determine all the possible extra abbreviations that might be encountered in the dataset and enter them by hand. Has anybody come up with a more general-purpose solution for this particular problem, even if it's just a long list of abbreviations that can be loaded from a file and passed as a parameter to the update method?

Comment: In my experience SpaCy's sentence tokenizer is usually able to distinguish abbreviations from end of sentence markers.

Answer (score -1):

SpaCy's sentence tokenizer will work that out for you.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
text = 'Exercise (e.g. riding a bike or taking a hike) will help you live longer. This is a second sentence'
doc = nlp(text)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
print(sentences)
```

Output:
['Exercise (e.g. riding a bike or taking a hike) will help you live longer.', 'This is a second sentence']